# Appcelerator leftImage

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-mobile

I'm trying to make my first mobile app using Appcelerator. When i try to load a local image into the array using "leftImage", the image doesn't show. However when i change the path to something that doesn't exist it tells me it can't find the path. I've googled it a lot and can't seem to find what i did wrong. Any help please?

```
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow(
    {
        title:'test',
        className:'win1',
        backgroundColor:'#000000'
    }
);

var vdata = [
        {leftImage:'appicons/cloudy.gif',title:"Schedule"},
        {leftImage:'appicons/shows.png',height:60, title:"Shows"},
        {leftImage:'appicons/search.png', title:"Search"},
        {leftImage:'appicons/friends.png',title:"Friends"},
        {leftImage:'appicons/settings.png',title:"Settings"}
    ];

var table1 = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    data:vdata
});
win1.add(table1);
win1.open();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

leftImage is the property of [Titanium.UI.TableViewRow](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.TableViewRow-object)

So, you should use this:

```
var row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({leftImage:'appicons/cloudy.gif',title:"Schedule"});

var table1 = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    data:row
});
win1.add(table1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ty this code

```
var tabledata;

var leftImage = ['appicons/cloudy.gif','appicons/shows.png','appicons/search.png','appicons/friends.png','appicons/settings.png'];
var title = ["Schedule", "Shows", "Search", "Friends", "Settings"];
for( var i = 0, len = title.length; i < len; i++)
{
      var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
                 leftImage:leftImage[i],
                 title:title[i]
      });
}

tabledata.push(row);

var table1 = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    data:tabledata
});
win1.add(table1);
```

You can also refer

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableViewRow-property-leftImage

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using leftImage as a property of data, use leftImage property with `Ti.UI.createtableViewRow`.

method 1:

```
var tblrow = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
   leftImage : imageURL
});
```

method 2:

```
$.tblrow.leftImage =  imageURL;
```